# Migrating to Linux from Windows but keep the old utorrent torrents

Tags: linux, debian, bittorrent, migration

I want to know if there is any possibility of using the utorrent in linux without losing the old files what are currently in seed. How do I have to do that? Can I do that?

I don't want to start collecting every stuff again and show the directory, etc etc etc.... If you have 400 seeding torrents it takes some time. The only thing I know, I have to mount the windows Partition what I want to use. But how to migrate all this stuff? Can you help me ?

Comment: What have you tried? Correct the spelling in the title. You will have get the torrent files out of the µtorrent cache directory (somewhere In AppData I believe) re-add them. After that you can let them point to the same directories in other to re-check them. I'm not sure you can just "import" them as the paths would change.

Comment: Please google for it. As an example, I use `transmission` and googling for `utorrent+migrate+transmission` yields lots of results including [this one](https://forum.transmissionbt.com/viewtopic.php?t=17619) pointing at a ready-made [tool](https://github.com/mikedld/bt-migrate) and hinting that solutions for migrating to Deluge, kTorrent, qBitTorrent etc do exist as well.

Comment: Thanks mate, will try :) 
I think that's what I need, if it can keep all the data and the paths.
Big up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using uTorrent on GNU/Linux, find the new uTorrent directory (likely `~/.utorrent` or `~/.config/utorrent`) and simply copy everything (most importantly the `resume.dat`) from the old directory, as the structure should be the same. On the Windows partition this should be located in `User\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent`.

If you're migrating to one of many other torrent clients on Linux, try looking for plugins or scripts to import. For example: [to migrate to Deluge](https://github.com/Laharah/deluge-uTorrentImport).

Comment: Really? My Windows resume.dat contains folder names like "e:\torrent downloads\something" Are those really going to be found by uTorrent on Ubuntu?